# Does $f_{n}(x)=\frac{x}{n}$ converge uniformly on $[0,2]$?

Tags: uniform-convergence

Does $f_{n}(x)=\frac{x}{n}$  converge uniformly on $[0,2]$?

Using the following definition of uniform convergence:
$\forall \epsilon$,$\exists N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $n\geqslant N$, then $\forall x\in Domain$,  $\left | f_{n}(x) - f(x) \right |<\epsilon $

Would it be correct to show that:

1) $f(x) =\lim_{n \to \infty }(\frac{x}{n})=0$

2)$\left | f_{n}(x) - f(x) \right | =\left | \frac{x}{n} - 0 \right |=\left | \frac{x}{n} \right |\leq \frac{2}{n}<\epsilon$

is true when we choose $n > \frac{\epsilon }{2}$ and thus $f_{n}(x)$ is uniformly convergent?

Comment: That's basically correct. You just forgot an inversion when you determine the bound for $n$. You need that $n$ is greater than $2/\epsilon$.

Comment: Why do you doubt your answer?

Comment: Thanks for comments. This type of math is completely new to me so was just trying to check if I'm thinking in the right direction.